# Connman error "passphrase required", but not making me input password

Tags: wifi, error-handling, connman

So I wanna connect to a wifi network, I click it and it doesn't show the window to input the password. It just shows this error:
"GDBus.Error:net.connman.Error.PassphraseRequired: Passphrase required". Same thing while using the connmanctl.

I am on Garuda Linux Wayfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue on Garuda Linux Wayfire.
I was able to work around it by writing a config file for my connection.

If you don't have an editor installed yet, you should be able use micro (it was pre-installed on my system).

Open a terminal.

Find out the name of you wireless interface by typing:

```
ip link
```

You get a list of interfaces. There should be one that is named wlan, wlo, wifi or something similar. Mine called wlan0 so I'm using it later. You should replace it with whatever you have.

In the following replace every instance of $SSID with the SSID of the wifi network you want to connect to:

Create/Open a config file with root privileges at /var/lib/connman/$SSID.config with the command:

```
sudo micro "/var/lib/connman/%SSID.config"
```

Write the following to the file:

```
[service_wifi_connection]
Type=wifi
IPv4=dhcp
IPv6=auto
DeviceName=wlan0
Name=$SSID
Passphrase=Your password
```

Don't forget to replace "Your password" with your actual wifi password.

Press Control + S to save the file and then Control + Q to quit.

Of course you can replace any of the options specified with something else and even add more options like nameservers, if you want to.
If you want to read into it, you can look at the man page for [connman-service.config](https://man.archlinux.org/man/connman-service.config.5).